# ¿Como puedo mapear con JPA y Hibernate una tabla que tiene dos FK?

Tags: java, base-de-datos, hibernate, jpa

Tengo que mapear las siguientes Tablas con JPA, se que es una relación de uno a muchos `@OneToMany` bidireccional lo que no me queda claro es cómo mapear la tabla intermedia con las dos FK.

[image: Diagrama E-R]

Answer (score 0):

Lo ideal sería que tu tabla intermedia use las FKs compuestas como PK y no tenga su propia PK. Luego harías lo que sigue (aclaro que no recuerdo haber implementado un caso como este y estoy leyendo la documentación para explicarlo):

```
@Embeddable
    class UserRoleKey implements Serializable {

    @Column(name = "user_id")
    Long userId;

    @Column(name = "role_id")
    Long roleId;

    // standard constructors, getters, and setters
    // hashcode and equals implementation
}
```

Eso modela la PK compuesta.

```
@Entity
class UserRole {

    @EmbeddedId
    UserRoleKey id;

    @ManyToOne
    @MapsId("userId")
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
    User user;

    @ManyToOne
    @MapsId("roleId")
    @JoinColumn(name = "role_id")
    Role role;

    Instant created;
    Instant updated;

    // standard constructors, getters, and setters
}
```

Eso modela la tabla en sí misma para poder usar las columnas created/updated.

```
class User {

    // ...

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user")
    Set<UserRole> roles;

    // ...
}

class Role {

    // ...

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "role")
    Set<UserRole> users;

    // ...
}
```

Finalmente ponemos las dos colecciones en ambas clases. Vale remarcar que si la tabla intermedia tuviese sólo dos columnas (o al menos sólo dos columnas se mapearan an JPA) esto sería mucho más fácil.